# How to make sure supervisord child process also get killed when supervisord dies?

Tags: linux, supervisord

I am using supervisord to monitor some java processes.The thing that I have observed with supervisord is if the main supervisord process dies due to some reason, the child process (java process whose parentid is supervisord main process id as long as supervisord is running) continues to run. Is there a provision in supervisord that if the main process dies all its child processes die too.

conf file for java process

```
command=/apps/shared/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java -jar /apps/sra-services/artifactory-event-reg-api/artifactory-event-reg-api.jar --application.decryptionKey=dev --spring.profiles.active=dev
user=udsraalm
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
startretries=3
stdout_logfile=/apps/sra-services/artifactory-event-reg-api-logs/artifactory-event-reg-api-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/apps/sra-services/artifactory-event-reg-api-logs/artifactory-event-reg-api-stderr.log
```

ps -ef | grep supervisord

```
 udsraalm 26631     1  0 07:16 ?        00:00:00 /users/udsraalm/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /users/udsraalm/usr/local/bin/supervisord
```

ps -ef | grep artifactory

```
udsraalm 26635 26631  3 07:16 ?        00:00:20 /apps/shared/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java -jar /apps/sra-services/artifactory-event-reg-api/artifactory-event-reg-api.jar --application.decryptionKey=dev --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

**After killing supervisord**

ps -ef | grep artifactory

```
udsraalm 26635     1  3 07:16 ?        00:00:20 /apps/shared/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java -jar /apps/sra-services/artifactory-event-reg-api/artifactory-event-reg-api.jar --application.decryptionKey=dev --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

As seen the child process does not get killed